# Science fiction comic from the 90s with power-armored religious troops fighting alien snakes

Tags: story-identification, comics, armor

I was wondering if anyone can remember a comic series I read in the 90s. I can’t remember the name and it’s driving me mad.

The protagonists were a religious order regiment of power-armored troops.

The setting had alien invaders that were small snakes a bit like the Goa'uld from *Stargate: SG1*, who could take over a body.

One of the regiment was an alien warrior slave used by the snakes as a front line troop. He had been freed of the snake. He was large, bipedal sauroid with a tail.

The armoured troops could be deployed from the air and compressed themselves into balls to survive the impact. I think they called the power armour ‘Iron’.

This ring any bells? What was it called?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you recall the style of the art?  Any details of their armour?  (For example, like WH40k space marines.)

Comment: Yes the armour had the same bulky ness as wh40k. I remember the art was very distinctive and was painted.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like Shadow Empires: Faith Conquers and it's follow up Sheva's War (although both were released as Graphic Novels as "Iron Empires: Faith Conquers" and "Iron Empires: Sheva's War" respectively).

The first four part run comic series, [Shadow Empires: Faith Conquers](https://www.darkhorse.com/Comics/93-299/Shadow-Empires-Faith-Conquers-1-of-4), was released in 1994.

The synopsis for the first issue is as follows:

> In the far future, humanity is in decline, the soul-possessing Vaylen are advancing, and man's only hope is Faith...
> On the distant outpost planet of Hotok, warrior-priest Faith and his elite troop, the Grey Rats, fight a desperate two-front war -- the alien Vaylen invading from the stars, and the decay and corruption they find in Hotok society itself. Shadow Empires is a beautifully painted science fiction epic in the tradition of Robert A. Heinlein!

[image: Shadow Empires Issue 1]

You can see the bulky armour types on the cover of the first issue. In universe these are known as [Irons](https://wiki.rpg.net/index.php/Iron_Empires_Glossary).

> Iron: Vernacular for a particular type of mechanized armor. It is
> perhaps a noble’s single greatest status symbol—an honor and a
> privilege allowed to only the nobility and the most accomplished
> warriors. The Iron Empires take their name from the symbolic image of
> wars and conquest led by nobles clad in iron. Though it is cumbersome,
> iron is ingenious in its design. It is a self contained environmental
> suit that turns a human being into a small tank. Power, locomotion,
> protection, and life support are all provided by the suit. An iron
> company is a formidable force.

The armour is better showcased on the cover of the Graphic Novel.
[image]

The alien Vaylen are worm like parasites that can control humanoids.

> Vaylen: A race of parasites, they're a cross between slugs and eels,
> unsavory but harmless in their natural state. When they come in
> contact with another creature's central nervous system (particularly
> with the brain), the Vaylen secrete an electrically conductive resin
> with which they control the nervous systems of much larger creatures,
> effectively short-circuiting the "will" of their host. Vaylen
> farm-worlds have become the concentration camps of the age, where
> people are harvested as hosts to their overlords

The five-issue follow up comic [Sheva's War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheva%27s_War) was released in 1998.

Either or both would fit the time period for the question.

There was another graphic novel in the series "Iron Empires: Void", but that wasn't released until 2013.

Comment: That’s it! Thank you so much. I haven’t read Shivas war, I will have to try and find it.